# Applying Remediation's for Vulnerabilities and Compliance Reported by Qualys Scan on RHEL 8.6

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, linux-kernel, rhel, rhel8

I recently conducted a `Qualys` scan on my `linux RHEL 8.6` system and received reports of vulnerabilities and compliance issues. I need guidance on how to apply the necessary remediation's to address these concerns. Specifically, I am looking for steps to resolve the following vulnerabilities:

Additionally, I have received compliance reports indicating non-compliance with specific standards (e.g., CIS benchmarks). I need guidance on how to bring my `RHEL 8.6` system into compliance with the following standards:

1. Description: Red Hat Update for python3 (RHSA-2023-3796)
   Severity: CRITICAL
2. Description: Red Hat Update for c-ares (RHSA-2023-3662)
   Severity: CRITICAL
3. Description: Red Hat Update for kernel security (RHSA-2023-3388)
   Severity: CRITICAL
4. Description: Red Hat Update for Open secure sockets layer (OpenSSL) (RHSA-2023-3408)
   Severity: CRITICAL
5. Description: Red Hat Update for gnutls (RHSA-2023-3361)
   Severity: CRITICAL
6. Description: OpenSSH Command Injection Vulnerability (Generic) - CVE-2020-15778
   Severity: CRITICAL

Additionally, I have received compliance reports indicating non-compliance with specific standards

1. Compliance: Status of the current setting for 'net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter'network parameter
2. Compliance: Status of the IPV4 nftables ruleset on loopback interface.

- For OpenSSH Command Injection Vulnerability,I have removed the execution permission for the scp binary as below.

  chmod 600 /usr/bin/scp
- For Compliance(Status of the current setting for `net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter` network parameter) I have enabled `RPFilter` in `strict` mode as below
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1
  sysctl -p